# How do I find out who initiated a group call?

Tags: skype

How can I figure out who initiated a Skype group call?

I am getting various unwanted group calls, and the call logs simply says "Group call" and "Missed group call."

Comment: This sounds like a question for [Skype customer service](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA1170/how-do-i-contact-skype-customer-service)

Comment: If you happen to be on / able to use Linux, the Linux version of Skype (basically a really outdated client) does show... then again not really a solution for everybody

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the "best" way to find who initiated a group call, but it worked in my case when the "Missed group call" message came up on one of my eighteen-participant sessions today.

The Skype UI only displays the orange phone/arrow graphic, "Missed group call" text, and a time AM/PM further to the right.

However, if you copy the message (i.e. hover over message text, right-click, select "Copy Message"). Then paste into a text editor or text field (e.g. the existing "Type a message here" field just below the the missed-call message works too), it will display the original message as well as the originating account name.

Example - 
"Missed group call."
 John Smith, Today 2:22 PM